# Can you explain purgatory and how to get out?

Tags: catholicism, death, afterlife, purgatory

We have the concept of purgatory.  I read in different places that purgatory happens after death.  But what should be stated clearly is whether they mean physical death or spiritual death when discussing this topic.  Nobody on Earth is wise enough to explain what happens after physical death, so I'm interested in this concept after spiritual death while still alive, because that's what people care about to stay healthy and alive.  Can someone explain how a person goes into purgatory, and how to get out?  I'd prefer an answer from the Catholic religion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you somewhat misunderstand Purgatory.

The state of Purgatory is entered into after physical death, not while one is alive.

Purgatory is a state of "purging" (the similarity of these words in not coincidental; they share the same Latin root) oneself of sin before entrance into Heaven; it is probably better envisioned as a process or journey to undergo, rather than an "endpoint" or place to "escape" from. One does not need to worry about being "trapped" in Purgatory; it a transitive, rather than final, state. Likewise, Heaven is more than merely the "paradise in the clouds" that is often depicted in media, just like Hell is more than the "underground inferno" that one might see on TV.

Among those not condemned to Hell, Purgatory is the "default", that most will go to through. The few that do not include the Virgin Mary(bodily assumed into heaven) and the martyrs.

How long does one stay in Purgatory? As long as we need to, to be come fully purified and fit for Heaven. This time can be reduced by abstinance from sin when alive, and the prayers and sacrifices of those still living.

Source: Catechism of the Catholic Church (CCC) 1030-1032, 1472, all emphasis mine.

> 1030 All who die in God's grace and friendship, but still imperfectly purified, are **indeed assured of their eternal salvation**; but **after death** they **undergo purification**, so as to achieve the holiness necessary to enter the joy of heaven.

> 1031 The Church gives the name Purgatory to this final purification of the elect, which is **entirely different from the punishment of the damned**. The Church formulated her doctrine of faith on Purgatory especially at the Councils of Florence and Trent. the tradition of the Church, by reference to certain texts of Scripture, speaks of a cleansing fire:
> As for certain lesser faults, we must believe that, before the Final Judgment, there is a purifying fire. He who is truth says that whoever utters blasphemy against the Holy Spirit will be pardoned neither in this age nor in the age to come. From this sentence we understand that certain offenses can be forgiven in this age, but certain others in the age to come.

> 1032 This teaching is also based on the practice of prayer for the dead, already mentioned in Sacred Scripture: "Therefore Judas Maccabeus] made atonement for the dead, that they might be delivered from their sin." From the beginning the Church has honored the memory of the dead and offered prayers in suffrage for them, above all the Eucharistic sacrifice, so that, thus purified, they may attain the beatific vision of God. The Church also commends almsgiving, indulgences, and works of penance undertaken on behalf of the dead:
>
> Let us help and commemorate them. If Job's sons were purified by their father's sacrifice, why would we doubt that our offerings for the dead bring them some consolation? Let us not hesitate to help those who have died and to offer our prayers for them.

> 1472 To understand this doctrine and practice of the Church, it is necessary to understand that sin has a double consequence. Grave sin deprives us of communion with God and therefore makes us incapable of eternal life, the privation of which is called the “eternal punishment” of sin. On the other hand every sin, even venial, entails **an unhealthy attachment to creatures, which must be purified either here on earth, or after death in the state called Purgatory. This purification frees one from what is called the “temporal punishment” of sin**. These two punishments must not be conceived of as a kind of vengeance inflicted by God from without, but as following from the very nature of sin. A conversion which proceeds from a fervent charity can attain the complete purification of the sinner in such a way that no punishment would remain

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you mean physical and spiritual death the way I interpret them the spiritually dead go to hell, there is no chance of them going to purgatory.

Purgatory is for the physically dead who still need to become perfect in order to enter heaven.

> 1030 All who die in God's grace and friendship, but still imperfectly purified, are indeed assured of their eternal salvation; but after death they undergo purification, so as to achieve the holiness necessary to enter the joy of heaven.
>
> 1031 The Church gives the name Purgatory to this final purification of
> the elect, which is entirely different from the punishment of the
> damned. The Church formulated her doctrine of faith on Purgatory
> especially at the Councils of Florence and Trent. the tradition of the
> Church, by reference to certain texts of Scripture, speaks of a
> cleansing fire:
>
> As for certain lesser faults, we must believe that, before the Final
> Judgment, there is a purifying fire. He who is truth says that whoever
> utters blasphemy against the Holy Spirit will be pardoned neither in
> this age nor in the age to come. From this sentence we understand that
> certain offenses can be forgiven in this age, but certain others in
> the age to come.

So how does one get out?

The living pray and offer indulgences/sacrifices for them.

> This teaching is also based on the practice of prayer for the dead, already mentioned in Sacred Scripture: "Therefore Judas Maccabeus] made atonement for the dead, that they might be delivered from their sin."607 From the beginning the Church has honored the memory of the dead and offered prayers in suffrage for them, above all the Eucharistic sacrifice, so that, thus purified, they may attain the beatific vision of God.608 The Church also commends almsgiving, indulgences, and works of penance undertaken on behalf of the dead:

[CCC 1030-1032](https://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG0015/__P2N.HTM)

Comment: I agree with everything in this answer, except for the formation of "So how does one get out? /The living pray and offer indulgences/sacrifices for them." which I only disagree with the implication that this is the "way out", rather than an aid in that process. Cf. CCC 1030 "assured of their eternal salvation", which is not dependent on the actions of the living.

Answer (score 0):

**Can you explain purgatory and how to get out?**

***Sin has consequences!***

Purgatory is basically a state where the soul is purified of all of remaining temporal punishments due to sin after the physical death of our earthly bodies.

> [**Purgatory**](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=35915&randomterm=false)
>
> The place or condition in which the souls of the just are purified after death and before they can enter heaven. They may be purified of the guilt of their venial sins, as in this life, by an act of contrition deriving from charity and performed with the help of grace. This sorrow does not, however, affect the punishment for sins, because in the next world there is no longer any possibility of merit. The souls are certainly purified by atoning for the temporal punishments due to sin by their willing acceptance of suffering imposed by God. The sufferings in purgatory are not the same for all, but proportioned to each person's degree of sinfulness. Moreover, these sufferings can be lessened in duration and intensity through the prayers and good works of the faithful on earth. Nor are the pains incompatible with great peace and joy, since the poor souls deeply love God and are sure they will reach heaven. As members of the Church Suffering, the souls in purgatory can intercede for the persons on earth, who are therefore encouraged to invoke their aid. Purgatory will not continue after the general judgment, but its duration for any particular souls continues until it is free from all guilt and punishment. Immediately on purification the soul is assumed into heaven. (Etym. Latin purgatio, cleansing, purifying.)

The vast, vast majority of souls that go to heaven will spend some time in purgatory. The best way to get out of purgatory is to avoid it all together. Live a holy life, frequently go to confession, have a sacramental based lifestyle and get take the holy habit of trying to get as many plenary indulgences as possible.

Indulgences are a remission of temporal punishments due to sin which have been sacramentally confessed and then absolved, thus making our purification in purgatory shorter. A plenary indulgence will remit all temporal punishments due to sin.

> An indulgence is a remission before God of the temporal punishment due to sins whose guilt has already been forgiven, which the faithful Christian who is duly disposed gains under certain prescribed conditions through the action of the Church which, as the minister of redemption, dispenses and applies with authority the treasury of the satisfactions of Christ and the saints. - (CCC 1471)

Even by doing so, there is a chance we will spend at least some time in purgatory.

It must be understood that once in purgatory a soul can nothing to get out any faster by his or her merits or prayers. These souls in a real sense are at the mercy of people on earth to pray for them so that they may freed of their sojourn in purgatory.

One more thing, I would like to draw your attention to is prearrange to have a set of 30 day Gregorian Masses offer for yourself after your death.  Gregorian Masses are said for just one particular soul at a time in Purgatory.

> **Gregorian Masses**
>
> During the 6th century, a deceased monk from St. Andrew’s Monastery in Rome (founded by St. Gregory) reportedly appeared to a friend and requested that 30 Masses be said to release his soul from purgatory. After the Masses were completed, the monk appeared again to declare he had entered heaven. Since that time, Catholics have continued the tradition of celebrating 30 consecutive Masses for one person to free his or her soul from purgatory. - [Gregorian Masses](https://cnewa.org/mass-intentions/gregorian-masses/)

The whole history of [Gregorian Masses](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_Masses) is absolutely interesting.